# Countdown var to loop and display array

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript and I'm trying to do something I thought would be very basic.

I've created a countdown timer and used "i" as my variable to hold a number from 0-5. And I have an array of "d" from d[0] to d[5] containing strings.

I'm trying to make the timer countdown pass the "i" value into an innerHTML method array value so I want it to display d[5]... d[4]...d[3]... etc.

What am I doing wrong!? Please Help!

```
<html><head><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var d=new Array():
    d[1]="One";
    d[2]="Two";
    d[3]="Three";
    d[4]="Four";
    d[5]="Five";

    var i=5;

    var i=setInterval("timer()",2000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

    function timer() {
        i--;
        if (i <= 0)

 clearInterval(countD);
 return;
      }
 }

 document.getElementById(timer).innerHTML = d[i];

 </script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <h1>
 <p id="timer"></p>
 </h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, `document.getElementById(timer).innerHTML = d[i];`

should be `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d[i];`

id names need to have quotes around them because they are not names of variables. The variable 'timer' is undefined.

Also, you are missing a curly brace on the line `if (i <= 0)`. I am assuming that you meant to exit the function if this if statement is true.

Also, you have a colon instead of a semicolon on the line `var d=new Array():`

Also, you can't have a paragraph tag inside of an h1

Also, you should encapsulate all of this javascript into a function called something like `init`. I believe that the javascript code in the head runs before the html is loaded. The javascript can't therefore find the

tag. Then, use `<body onload="init()">` as your body tag.

EDIT: As the commenters have stated, you are using the variable i for multiple unrelated things.

Comment: and array indexing starts from `0` and `i` is defined twice and `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d[i];` is outside of the timed function.

Comment: And `setInterval` functions don't need the quotes: `setInterval(timer,...)`

Comment: `i` is *declared* twice, the second assignment replaces the value of the first (it's not used anyway). I presume the second should have been `var countD = setInterval(...);`.

Comment: You're wrong about the `setInterval` invocation - it's correct the way it is - the first parameter will get `eval`ed if it's a string - passing in `"timer"` will cause nothing to happen, passing in `"timer()"` will cause the `timer` function to be called.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me about the setInterval thing. I've corrected it in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say but your code is quite a mess; here's one way to get your code to work, along with [**a working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/F2FkP/):

```
<html>
<head>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var d=new Array();
    d[0]="One";
    d[1]="Two";
    d[2]="Three";
    d[3]="Four";
    d[4]="Five";

    var i=4;

    var myTimer =setInterval(timer,2000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

    function timer() {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d[i];
        i--;
        if (i < 0){
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>
        <p id="timer"></p>
    </h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

---

**The problems with your JavaScript**

- You've got two declarations for `i`, one after the other - one is set to `5` and the other to the `setInterval` timer
- What is `countD` in `clearInterval(countD);`?
- `document.getElementById(timer).innerHTML = d[i];` is attempting to use the function `timer` as the argument to `getElementById`. It should be in quotes: `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d[i];`

  - It is also being invoked only once since it's not inside the function that is being called by the timer.
- `var d=new Array():` should be terminated by a `;`(semi-colon) and not a `:` (colon)
- You have unmatched braces - your `if` statement doesn't have an opening brace (`{`) but it does have a closing one.
- Note that while `setInterval("timer()", 1000)` is valid JavaScript, it depends on `eval` which should be avoided if possible. The alternate, preferred way to use this is `setInterval(timer, 1000)` i.e. passing the function and not a string.